# How many tests for the same class?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-5, integration-testing

I am using PHP Laravel framework and have a Controller class.

I have written a unit test for the class.

Is it also necessary to write integration test for the same class?

Or do Controller classes only need integration instead of unit tests?

How about for Repository classes that call Eloquent Models and  also Adapters that call third party packages?

Should they only have integration tests, since they are not under my control?

Thanks